# How to generate an API index?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

We are using MediaWiki for the prose documentation of our C#/Java/Javascript programming API. The API methods and properties are listed on about 20 wiki pages grouped by topic (e.g. frontend/client-server-interaction/backend).

What I need is an alphabetic index of all API methods similar to [Sphinx API Index](http://sphinx-doc.org/genindex.html). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Put your 20 wiki pages in the "API" [category](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aCategories) by adding `[[Category:API]]` to the page's wikitext.  Then, when you visit the Category:API page (`http://your-wiki-url/Category:API`), you'll see all those API pages listed.

Comment: I thought of that solution, but it wouldn't give me a listing for each API command since there is more than one command on each wiki page

Comment: @fbuchinger: You could create redirects for all the API commands, pointing to the appropriate sections on the actual pages, and add those redirects to the category.